# Why is my Windows Service not showing in Services after it installs?

Tags: .net-3.5

I've created a Setup Project to create an installer for my Windows service I am writing.  The Windows service has a ProjectInstaller and the ProjectIsntaller has a ServiceInstaller and ServiceProcessInstaller.  When I compile and install the MSI created for the service, the files copy to the correct directory but the actually service doesn't appear to be registered in the Services panel.  Any idea what is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you add custom actions in setup project?

To add a custom action to the setup project

1. In Solution Explorer, right-click the setup project, point to View, and then click Custom Actions.

   The Custom Actions editor appears.
2. In the Custom Actions editor, right-click the Custom Actions node and choose Add Custom Action.

   The Select Item in Project dialog box appears.
3. Double-click the Application Folder in the list box to open it, select Primary Output from MyNewService (Active), and click OK.

   The primary output is added to all four nodes of the custom actions — Install, Commit, Rollback, and Uninstall.
4. In Solution Explorer, right-click the MyServiceSetup project and click Build.

see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a(VS.80).aspx)

Comment: I had completely forgotten about the custom actions!  Thanks for reminding me!